# Check if list has n consecutive values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am making a base converter that includes a radix point using Python. I am trying to make the float result end itself if it sees four or more 0's in a row. However, I have no idea how to do this. This is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
import math

num = 0.25
base = 4

x = list()

b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
a = 0

if isinstance(num, float) == True:
    x.append('.')
    while num != 0 or d <= 100:
        b = math.floor(num / (base ** a))
        x.append(b)
            
        num = num - (b * (base ** a))
        d += 1
        a -= 1

print(*x, sep="")
```

Though the values for this snippet are fixed, if I changed `num` to `10.4` and the base to `10`, I would get `10.400000000000000333066907387546967...` (200 digits omitted). I get about 10-15 correct digits, but after a trail of zeroes, a large amount of "junk" numbers appear.

If I let `num = 2.5` and `base = 2`, then I get `10.10000000000000000000000`, with many extra trailing zeros. I need to clear these extra digits after four consecutive 0's are seen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please visit and read https://stackoverflow.com/help .
It sounds like a homework question. Provide as a minimal working example. Your code looks to complex for your question. Provide us with input and expected output data examples.

Comment: @buhtz, I have compacted my code.

Comment: Can you include some sample input output?

Comment: @arsho I have included more specification about the outputs.

Comment: I changed `num` to `10.4` and `base` to `10` in the above code. I am getting `ZeroDivisionError` in line `b = math.floor(num / (base ** a))`. Can you please check?

Comment: It works for me. I am only including the decimal part, rather than the whole number. It works for me; I am using Python 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do this if `'num'` is the number which causes the problem:

```
#form the output of the given code, 'x' has the value in the form of a list
#converting the list to string:
num=""
for digit in x:
    num+=str(digit)
y=float(num)
print (format(num, '.4f'))
```

This worked for me! Hope it works for you...

Comment: @fasterthanlight first, convert x(which is a list) into string. Then typecast it into float and finally pass the last print statement given above. Hope it helps..

Comment: @fasterthanlight I have done the edits. You can take a look

Comment: That doesn't work. It outputs `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`, at line 19 `num+=x`

Comment: Yes, but your code is not working, it gives TypeError.

Comment: @fasterthanlight I have done the edit. It now works fine  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216293/discussion-between-fasterthanlight-and-crazyguy).

Comment: @fasterthanlight check out the chat